# Does rooting void s4 warranty if the thing that is wrong is not the fault of rooting?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-knox, warranty

I have a galaxy s4 from AT&T with knox on it. And I just want to root (no custom roms) but if my phone breaks or something I don't want to void my warranty because it's rooted. So is my warranty voided automatically with root or is it voided only if the root is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rooting your phone will void the warranty from both the carrier and the manufacturer.

No matter what happens to be wrong. If they found that the phone's rooted then you'll have to face the consequences.

**So your warranty will be void automatically with root. **

Comment: Is this true with just Samsung? Because I heard some stories of people who had it rooted and sent it in and got it back fixed

Comment: They rarely check the device I think.

Comment: My friend's touch screen got fixed without any problem. It was for rooted phone.

Comment: Was it with samsung?

Comment: Yes it was Samsung Galaxy Ace plus

Comment: Did he send it TO samsung though? Or the carrier

Comment: He did send it to the Samsung

Comment: So what root method would you reccomend? Chainfire autoroot?

Comment: All methods are good. Almost all methods provide option to unroot if wanted. ChainFire is one of the most accepted method. You can search xda forums for your device's root method. The best are there.

Comment: I was looking at cf autoroot site and it says the att version of the s4 is not supported

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify your model and version.

Comment: My device is SGH-i337

Comment: I've tried searching. There are many methods working for your model. But any slight variations in build number, version number, Android version etc will have a new method for rooting. So I recommend you to search xda and select the most appropriate method for your device. There are many. Even if you mistakes there's a solution. So no need to worry

Answer (score 0):

Your friends just got lucky. thats it. No manufacture in this world will provide you warranty services after you have rooted the device.